# Multi-Threaded TCP Listner (Server) in C#

Tags: c#, tcplistener

**Intro:**
I have developed a Server (TCP Listener) program developed in C# which runs at specific (constant) IP at specific (constant) port. This server program receives data packet sent by client programs, process it and sends back data packet to same socket. Whilst the number of client programs for this server may be in hundreds:

**Code Sample**

```
while(true)
{
    socket = Host.AcceptSocket();
    int len = socket.Receive(msgA);

    performActivities(msgA); // May take up-to 5 seconds

    socket.Send(msgB);
    socket.Close();
}
```

**Problem:**
Due to some critical business requirements, processing may take up-to 5 seconds hence other requests during this time are queued which I need to avoid so that every request must be entertained in not more than 5 seconds.

**Query:**
I can make it multi-threaded but (pardon me if you find me novice):

how one socket will receive another packet from different clients if it is still opened by previous thread?

In case of entertaining multi-requests, how this can be made sure that response is sent back to respective clients?

Comment: [this tutorial](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-server-socket.htm) might be a good start. Basically your listener can listen to multiple ports, and it will send to the accepted client over that specific port. This will ensure that the correct client is reached.

Comment: [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cjf5pfS-y8) might also be quite helpful. Jump to minute 15:40 and in 1 minute you should know whether it can help you. Good luck

Comment: Some of the naming and code makes me want to add my usual caution: TCP offers *streams of bytes* in both directions. *not* messages. If you want messages, it's up to *you* to introduce message framing or to move to a higher level protocol that does messaging for you. `Receive` is only guaranteed to return at least *one* byte if it succeeds. So pay attention to `len` and if you want `msgA` to actually contain a *complete* message (and also not multiple message fragment(s)), you have more work to do.

Comment: I would use the TcpListener class. It's a thin wrapper on sockets, very easy to use, plus you have async (means it will run in parallel and you don't need "multithreaded" stuf) almost for free. An example is here: https://gist.github.com/jamesmanning/2622054

Answer (score 9):

Building an efficient, multi-threaded socket server requires strong knowledge and skills in that area. My proposal is instead of trying to build your own TCP server from scratch, use one of the existing libraries, that already solved this problem. Few that come to my mind are:

- [DotNetty](https://github.com/Azure/DotNetty/tree/dev/examples) used on Azure IoT services.
- [System.IO.Pipelines](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/tree/master/samples/System.IO.Pipelines.Samples) which is experimental, but already quite *fast*.
- [Akka.Streams TCP stream](http://getakka.net/articles/streams/workingwithstreamingio.html).

Each one of those libs covers things like:

- Management of a TCP connection lifecycle.
- Efficient management of byte buffers. Allocating new `byte[]` for every package is highly inefficient and causes a lot of GC pressure.
- Safe access to socket API (sockets are not thread-safe by default).
- Buffering of incoming packets.
- Abstraction in form of handlers/pipes/stages, that allow you to compose and manipulate binary payload for further processing. This is particularly useful i.e. when you want to operate on the incoming data in terms of messages - by default TCP is a binary stream and it doesn't know when one message inside the pipeline ends and another one starts.

Writing a **production-ready** TCP server is a tremendous work. Unless you're an expert in network programming with a very specific requirements, you should never write the one from scratch.

Comment: If OP wan't to roll his own let him.  Don't promote some 3rd party lib which is an example of someone _"rolling their own"_ anyway.  You don't learn if you use pre-fab.   Where would Apache be with this attitude? :)

Comment: The phrase *Due to some critical business requirements* from original question suggests, that this is not learning project, but something that will be used on production. Not good place to experiment IMHO ;)

Comment: True, but can  you show those libs satisfy the business requirements?

Comment: Every one of these libs can work as TCP server handling multiple concurrent clients with package buffering and efficient byte buffer management. That's even more than described by the author. What do you want me to show here specifically?

Comment: The onus is on you to demonstrate that these libs meet the OP's requirements since you brought it up in the first place.

Comment: The topic of writing socket server is very broad. Each of the links, I've attached, points either to documentation with code snippets or to the samples showing several different use cases. I believe this is way more informative and useful than you could fit in a single SO answer. So please show me, how is that not demonstrative?

Comment: MickyD the fact, that I've contributed to an OS lib that does that is more an argument for my opinion, not against it. I've done that thing. I know the struggle. I want to save author's time and nerves, because his question suggests, that TCP server is a mean to achieve a business goal, not the goal by itself. My answer is what a responsible person would advise.

Comment: Thank-you for expanding your answer to summarise those links. Flag and vote reversed

Comment: Thank you all for your prompt responses. @Horusiath Unfortunately as a company policy we cannot use any third party dlls in our project but nevertheless I appreciate your expert comments.